# Remove single occurrences of words in vocabulary TF-IDF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am attempting to remove words that occur once in my vocabulary to reduce my vocabulary size. I am using the sklearn TfidfVectorizer() and then the fit_transform function on my data frame.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()  
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(df['original_post'].values.astype('U'))
```

My first thought is the preprocessor field in the tfidf vectorizer or using the preprocessing package before machine learning.

Any tips or links to further implementation?

Answer (score 19):

you are looking for `min_df` param (minimum frequency), from the documentation of scikit-learn [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> **min_df : float in range [0.0, 1.0] or int, default=1**
>
> When building the vocabulary ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly lower than the given threshold. This value is also
>   called cut-off in the literature. If float, the parameter represents a
>   proportion of documents, integer absolute counts. This parameter is
>   ignored if vocabulary is not None.

```
# remove words occuring less than 5 times
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5)
```

you can also remove common words:

```
# remove words occuring in more than half the documents
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5)
```

you can also remove stopwords like this:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
```

Answer (score 3):

ShmulikA's answer will most likely work well but will remove words based on document frequency. Thus, if the specific word occurs 200 times in only 1 document, it will be removed. TF-IDF vectorizer does not provide exactly what you want. You would have to:

1. Fit the vectorizer to your corpus. Extract the complete vocabulary from the vectorizer
2. Take the words as keys in a new dictionary.
3. count every word occurrence:

`for every document in corpus: for word in document: vocabulary[word] += 1`

Now, find out if there are values = 1, drop these entries from the dictionary. Put the keys into a list and pass the list as parameter to the TF-IDF vectorizer. 
It will need a lot of looping, maybe just use min_df, which works well in practice.